# Ansible multiple facts in Jinja template

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2

I want to pull all the interface names from a host and then print all the information of that interface.

```
--- # Fetches network interfaces with IPs
- hosts: hta
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tasks
- debug: msg=" {{ ansible_interfaces|length }}"
  register: num
- name: moving template over to server
  template: src=templates/network.j2 dest=/root/network_info.txt
```

And the network.j2 file

```
{% for int in ansible_interfaces %}
Interfaces: Interface-{{ int }}
Data: ansible_{{ int }}
{% endfor %}
```

So far i couldn't print the information and Ansible takes my input ansible_{{ int }} as literal.

Answer (score 0):

The play below

```
- command: "ifconfig {{ item }}"
  register: result
  loop: "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"
- template:
    src: template.j2
    dest: int.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
```

with this template

```
{% for int in result.results %}
Interfaces: Interface-{{ int.item }}
Data: {{ int.stdout }}
{% endfor %}
```

creates at *localhost* the file *int.txt* with the interfaces' data.

Comment: i got the following error 
"AnsibleError: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'pipe'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: lookup_plugin.pipe(ifconfig eth1) returned 1"}

Comment: Sorry i don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: Like all lookups, pipe will run on the ansible controller host so it will never fetch the info from the remote host

Answer (score 0):

What I dont really get is that you are calling a server to gather info about its interfaces and send a file back to that same server with the info you could gather again any time. I don't really see the point but here we go.

Applying the KISS principle: call `ifconfig` which will return details about all the interfaces and store the result in a file on remote host

playbook.yml

```yaml
- name: Simple interface info dump on hosts
  hosts: whatevergroup_you_need
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  
  tasks:
    - name: dump ifconfig result to /root/network_interface.txt
      shell: ifconfig > /root/network_interfaces.txt
```

Notes:

- `become: true` is only needed because you want to write your file in root's home. If you write the file anywhere else with proper permissions, `ifconfig` itself is executable by anyone
- Since there is no need to collect any other info from the host, `gather_facts: false` will speed up the playbook for this one single easy task.
- `shell` module is mandatory for the output redirection to the file. If you are concerned about security, you can use the `command` module instead (without the file redirection), capture the output with `register` and write the content to a file in a next task
- I assumed you were calling a linux host and that `ifconfig` was outputing the info you need. If it is not the case, you need to rewrite your question and be more accurate about what you are trying to achieve.